# Error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
export function output(functions: Function[], inputs: unknown[]) {
    for (let func of functions) {
        console.log(`=== ${func.name} ===`);
        for (let input of inputs) {
            console.log(`"${input}"\t-> ${func(input)}`);
        }
        console.log();
    }
}
```

It works fine. However the tsc compiler complains on this line:

```
console.log(`=== ${func.name} ===`);
```

Saying:

> Error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'.

What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem.  It looks like the lib.d.ts file that defines the interface for Function doesn't have "name" as a property.

See [Typescript Issue 6623](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6623), which has a workaround.

> The name property on interface Function is defined in `lib.es6.d.ts`. If
>   you compile with `--target ES6` you should see it.